# Invariant subspaces of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone show me how to find all invariant subspaces of the real linear operator whose matrix is: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I have another example, so I would like to know how to proceed with the above example so that I can redo it again.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Obviously $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\{ 0 \}$ are invariant subspaces. The one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written $t\mathbf{a}$ for some vector $\mathbf{a}\neq\mathbf{0}$. Under what condition is $L(t\mathbf{a}) = tL(\mathbf{a})$ a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{a}$?

Comment: Can you detail a bit more. I have another example to train on..

Comment: What did you try? Do you know about eigenvectors? If not, write $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, a_2)$ and compute $L(\mathbf{a})$ to give you some equations.

Comment: I do know about eigenvectors